# Import-Module from GAC for PowerShell Usage

Tags: powershell, gac

I have created a powershell module that works just fine if I load it like this

```
Import-Module "C:\temp\My.PowerShell.DocumentConversion.dll"
```

I did register the module in the global assembly cache as well but can't load it from there. I have verified that the module in fact is loaded in the gac. I figured that it would be sufficient to load the module like this

```
Import-Module My.PowerShell.DocumentConversion.dll
```

Obviously I was wrong, how do one do to run powershell modules from gac?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -Assembly My.PowerShell.DocumentConversion
```

If it's not working try the [LoadWithPartialName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadwithpartialname) method:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('My.PowerShell.DocumentConversion')
```

Or using the full path:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(...)
```

Comment: Or using the full path:

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(...)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the assembly is in the GAC, just use the strong name to reference the assembly.
To get the path to the GAC be aware it has changed in .Net 4.0 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache

```
$assemblyPath = 'path to the assembly file in the gac'
$fullName = [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($assemblyPath).FullName
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($fullName)
```